# Upload file > 25 MB on Github

Tags: git, github

I have a file that I want to add to Github. Its size is more than 25 MB limit of github. It is a csv file. How can I upload it on Github.

Steps followed till now

```
$ cd path_of_directory
$ git lfs install
$ git lfs track "*.csv"
$ git add Filename.csv
$ git commit -m "Filename.csv"
```

Till here everything is fine. I get below success message:

```
$ git commit -m 'FileName.csv'
[master (root-commit) 3f089ff] FileName.csv
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 Downloads/Folder_of_file/FileName.csv


$ git push origin master
```

This gives error

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Quick note: GitHub bandwidth limits: `Github Upload via Browser Limit - 25 MB` and 
`GitHub Upload via CLI (No Git-LFS) - 50 MB (Warning)` and 
`Github Upload via CLI (No Git-LFS) - 100 MB (Error)` and
`Github Upload via CLI with Git-LFS - 1 GB (Resets every 30 days)` and 
`Github Upload via CLI with Git-LFS and Data Plan - $5 per 30 for 50 GB`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Files that you add to a repository via a browser are limited to 25 MB
>   per file. You can add larger files, up to 100 MB each, via the command
>   line.

Refer [this](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/adding-a-file-to-a-repository) page.

If you need to upload greater file than 100 mb then **[Git LFS](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files)** might be suitable for you.

Comment: Note to anonymous: If you are using free github plan, Git LFS Data
Bandwidth quota is 1GB i.e. that lfs repo will be suspended for next 30 days and you will receive email to upgrade plans.

Comment: How does this work if you want to upload a `new release` bigger than 25MB?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some >25MB files to your release you can not use the browser and you need to use `Github gh` CLI command.

See these simplified Windows helper batchfiles. It supports multiple files using wildcards.
For more examples and parameters see https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_create

`publishNewRelease.bat`:

```
@echo off

set TAG_NAME=v1.1
set RELEASE_TITLE=My Awesome Release
set RELEASE_NOTES=

:: Create the release
gh release create %TAG_NAME% --title "%RELEASE_TITLE%" --notes "%RELEASE_NOTES%"

call uploadFilesForRelease.bat %TAG_NAME% .\Builds\netcoreapp3.1\*.zip
call uploadFilesForRelease.bat %TAG_NAME% .\Builds\net6.0\*.zip
```

`uploadFilesForRelease.bat`:

```
set TAG_NAME=%1
set FILES_TO_UPLOAD=%2

:: Upload files to the release
for %%f in (%FILES_TO_UPLOAD%) do (
  gh release upload %TAG_NAME% "%%f"
)
```