# Upload large amount of files to github

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I've seen numerous guides on how to push large files to github, but not how to push a large *amount* of files.

I have a folder on my desktop that has 600 MB worth of text files that I need to push to a github repository.

I can't upload them directly b/c they exceed github's limitations. I have also tried to upload them from git bash:

```html
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m “First commit”
$ git remote add origin remote repository URL
$ git push origin master
```

But this doesn't run, and even if it did, I believe it would just upload all of the files directly into the repository.

Ideally, I have a repository with a separate folder inside of it, and I need to push all 600 MB worth of files into this folder.

Please let me know how I can best go about achieving this!

Comment: Can't you split the files into multiple commits?

Comment: Instead of `git add .`, use `git add filename` (while using git client with UI it is much easier), and push files in batches. On the other hand - do you need to hold those text files in git repository? Remember, that git is not just a file storage. If those files are some data files for your application, consider whether you should have them in git repo; or you could, for example, compress them to zip and store as archive, or something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload file > 25 MB on Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040990/upload-file-25-mb-on-github)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Git LFS which stores the large files, usually used for binary files, in a folder away from the repository.

A link is included below,

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files